# Increase Google GeoCoding API Limits

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have 1 window service which uses Google geocoder. I will have 1,00,000 request for geocoding each day by 1 customer and also I will have more than 10 customers.
Every Customer will have their Business key for google and my window service will work only in 1 server system. So I will have only 1 IP address with multiple Google
Business Keys. But Google Api allows only 1,00,000 request per IP Address for Business client.
So Will google allow to geocode such all requests ? What is the solution to geocode all requests ?

Answer (score 1):

Refferring to the [usage limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#usage_limits) google allows 100.000 requests/day per client-ID, it doesn't matter from which IP the requests come from, google should allow all requests.

*These limits apply to each Maps API for Business client ID and are shared across all applications and IP addresses using a given client ID.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by a "window service", but for distributed web applications where multiple customers are making the geocoding requests, it generally makes more sense to use the [client-side Javascript Geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#client), not the Geocoding web service.  This way your customers can talk to Google directly, instead of having to route all requests through your server.

See also: [Geocoding Strategies: When to Use Client-Side Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#client)